# Use JBPM without console in WebLogic

Tags: weblogic, jbpm, business-process-management

my purpose is to integrate jbpm (in particular version 3.2.1) in weblogic(last version 12c).
I have resolved many problem of compatibility and integration but jbpm still doesn't work, in particular the console. It's possible to use jbpm without console? (i'm new in the use of jbpm and bpm in general). 
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

jBPM Console should be able to run on weblogic (you would need to configure it for the different transcation manager and persistence etc. will be different to set up).  You can also use jBPM without the console at all, just embed the jBPM engine in your webapp.

Comment: Can you give me a tutorial to use it without console? In particular when the console start and i want to deploy a process the console redirect to error page and log no error. I have just solved problem of transaction and persistance at all.